# List of css properties that are not supported in mobile devices

Tags: android, css, ipad, mobile, browser

I have a application up and running in all PC browsers(IE7+ FF3.6F etc),
Now I want the same look and feel in IOS, Android browsers and Opera, I was able to add mobile specific css file, but I guess some css property are not supported by these hand-held device browsers. ex:  I think clear:both is not supported in Ipad 2.

If some one has come across same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check: http://caniuse.com
iOS safari, Opera Mobile, Android browser